# I am not able to import pywinauto into my program

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am not able to import pywinauto into my program, I have installed pywinauto using pip and I checked to see if I have the latest python downloaded on my machine. This is the error message I am getting:

import pywinauto
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywinauto'

please help!

Comment: what is output you see of `python -m pip freeze | grep pywinauto`?

Comment: `pip install pywinauto`.  here is the link: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: C:\Users\RR>python -m pip freeze
comtypes==1.1.14
pywin32==304
pywinauto==0.6.8
six==1.16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that pywinauto is downloaded in pycharm and not just in your base python installation.  Check in cmd using pip list to see if it is installed in base installation and to see it in pycharm go to File > settings... > Check you python interpreter if it is correct one else check the package is listed or not, if not then click on + icon, search and install. If you are behind a corporate firewall and ran into a problem searching for the package you can do this: I went through Settings/Appearance and Behavior/System Settings/HTTP Proxy and check Auto-detect proxy settings and it let me search and find pywinauto. Thank you to all who helped contribute to this answer in this thread

Answer (score 0):

Please don't name your script `pywinauto.py`. :) It's a typical reason for such error. Python tries to find module `pywinauto` in a current directory first and it finds your .py file. That's it.

P.S. Please always provide full traceback (copy all lines of the output) including name of your script in all Python questions. It makes any problem more clear.

Comment: This is the full traceback error, my script has a different name that is not pywinauto.py  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RR\PycharmProjects\pythonAutomationproj\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pywinauto
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywinauto'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @Rae Have you installed the pywinauto in pycharm or in your base python installation?
 Check in cmd using pip list to see if it is installed in base installation and to see it in pycharm go to File > settings... > Check you python interpreter if it is correct one else check the package is listed or not, if not then click on + icon, search and install.

Comment: One more way to determine the Python interpreter path is `import sys; print(sys.executable)`. If it is different in cmd.exe python interpreter and PyCharm, this is the answer.

Comment: @Dev Thank you so much this worked, for installation, I am also behind a corporate firewall and ran into a problem searching for the package. I went through Settings/Appearance and Behavior/System Settings/HTTP Proxy and check Auto-detect proxy settings and it let me search and find pywinauto !! Thank you so much again!

Comment: @Rae please post this solution as an answer and accept it (yes, you can check your own answer as accepted, no problem).